# Force WebChromeClient instead of WebViewClient

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, webview

I am currently working on a mobile android app containing webcontent into a WebView.

As far as i understood well, some phones used WebChromeClient, some other WebViewClient, I guess depending on Android version.

My app works well, but I found some CSS rendering issues. If i fix them on classical webview, chromeClient is broken, and opposite :)

Tested on my S3 (android 4.3) seems to use WebViewClient
and MotoG (android 4.4) seems to use WebChromeClient.

Any advice to deal with that ? Is there anything to do to force one of webview client on every device ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "As far as i understood well, some phones used WebChromeClient, some other WebViewClient, I guess depending on Android version" -- [the  `WebViewClient` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) is not a replacement for [the `WebChromeClient` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html). Both have existed since API Level 1 and both are part of every Android device with `WebView` support (e.g., not Android Wear).

Answer (score 3):

Android 4.4 (API level 19) has introduced a new version of the `WebView` that is based on Chromium. That might be the reason why you get different renders on your S3 and your Moto G.

Setting your `targetSdkVersion` in your manifest file to 18 or lower will make your `WebView` for API 19 and higher operate in "quirks mode" which means that it will try to have the same behavior as you would have on a lower API device.

See the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html) for more details. I hope that solves your problem.